# Web scraping Iframe page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am currently running a web scraper on a webpage which works perfectly. However, because the data I require is spread across multiple pages of the same site, I decided to use the iframe html tag to combine 20 of these pages.

Having done this, I am unable to scrape the data from the iframes as I would if I was to scrape the individual pages. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to retrieve the source code of each iframe, so the webscraper can do its job? Or would I have to modify the webscraper?

Any help appreciated.

The web scraper I am using is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en.

Comment: No, you can't scrape iframes unless it's explicitly allowed by the content provider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scrape website content (\*COMPLEX\* iframe, javascript submission)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481699/how-to-scrape-website-content-complex-iframe-javascript-submission)